# Delphi: Reference vs Copy of TADoConnection variable assignment

Tags: delphi, variable-assignment, adoconnection

I am trying to understand how Delphi handles an assignment. I have a global connection that is called `GlobalConn` (`TADoConnection`)...

i have a function that makes a database call using the variable passed in:

```
function MakeDBCall( AConnection : TAdoConnection )
var LocalConn : TAdoConn;
begin
   LocalConn := TAdoConnection.Create(nil);
   try
       LocalConn := AConnection
       ///create the table and perform action using the LocalConn
   finally
       LocalConn.free;    
   end;
end;
```

A call would be made using `MakeDbCall`(`GlobalConn`);

1. What actually happens when `LocalConn := AConnection` (inside the function)? Is the reference count increased or a new copy assigned to the local variable?
2. Does freeing the `LocalConn` impact the `GlobalConn`?
3. Ideally i presume that making a copy is better (faster) than taking the connection string and assigning to the local variable and opening... is this a correct presumption?
4. Is this handled differently from Delphi 7 and XE7-Xe10?

thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this and not just using AConnection itself?  Your call to TAdoConnection.Create creates a new instance on the heap.  You effectively discard that by assigning LocalConn to AConnection and then effectively call Free on AConnection by LocalConn.Free.  So by the time your procedure exits, you've Free'd the wrong object and created a memory leak by the discard of the TAdoConnection object you created.

Comment: It does not work as you think, you are overwriting the local variable with the global (and thus leaking the locally created connection) and at the end you are freeing the global var, resulting in an AV the next time you are going to use the global var...

Comment: @whosrdaddy:  well put!

Comment: Hi all - thanks for the comments. What is the best way to have the local variable use a "copy" of the existing (global-already opened) connection - without having to open a new connection? And when i say open meaning to create a new connection object and set the connectionstring and then open. My presumption is that multiple opening of the connection will create some lag time.

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not do what you think it does. I've put in some comments to try to explain exactly what's happening.

```
function MakeDBCall( AConnection : TAdoConnection )
var 
  LocalConn : TAdoConn;
begin
  // This creates a brand new ADO connection. 
  LocalConn := TAdoConnection.Create(nil);
  try
    // This line discards the connection you've just created, 
    // orphaning it (leaking the memory), and sets LocalConn
    // to point to the object passed in as AConnection.
    LocalConn := AConnection

    ///create the table and perform action using the LocalConn
  finally
    // This line frees AConnection, making your global variable invalid
    LocalConn.free;    
  end;
end;
```

So to deal with the questions you asked directly:

> 1. What actually happens when LocalConn := AConnection (inside the function)? Is the reference count increased or a new copy assigned to the local variable?

None of the above.

The assignment discards the brand new connection you just created, leaking the memory that was allocated, and `LocalConn` becomes a new variable that points to `AConnection`, not a copy. `TADOConnection` is not an interface, and therefore is not subject to reference counting. No new copy is assigned - `LocalConn` is just another variable that points to the connection instance you passed in to the function.

> 2. Does freeing the LocalConn impact the GlobalConn?

Yes. It frees `AConnection`, making any references to it invalid, presumably your global connection instance. (It does nothing to the local connection you created with `TADOConnection.Create(nil)`; that memory is leaked, because you discarded the only reference to it that could be used to free it.

> 3. Ideally i presume that making a copy is better (faster) than taking the connection string and assigning to the local variable and opening... is this a correct presumption?

It might be, if in fact you were making a copy, but you're not.

> 4. Is this handled differently from Delphi 7 and XE7-Xe10?

No. What I pointed out above is the same for every version of Delphi from v1 onward when dealing with the VCL and Windows. (FMX on mobile changes some things, but it wouldn't change the fact that you're still freeing the global object in error.)

If `TADOConnection` actually implements the `Assign` method, you can use it. It's unclear from the documentation, however, whether it is implemented or not; the documentation links to `TPersistent.Assign`. You can check the source for the version of Delphi you're actually using (I don't have D2007 on this laptop) to see if it's implemented. If it is, you can use something like this:

```
LocalConn := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
try
  LocalConn.Assign(AConnection);
  // Use LocalConn
finally
  LocalConn.Free;  // Frees the local copy
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the information and advice. My confusion was based on not realizing what happens when the assignment "operator" is used. Here is a link to the Embarcadero folks that added to my understanding: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TPersistent_Assign.html.